# Avoid jnlp "Open" click in MSIE9

Tags: java, security, internet-explorer, java-web-start, jnlp

I have an applet started by jnlp/javaws and it generally works well on all combinations of browsers/OS. So the mime type etc. is correct. The only issue is that when using MSIE 9 (and only that) after downloading the jnlp the bar at the lower edge of the browser window appears where you have to click "Open" to start the javaws.

There is no checkbox like "Do this every time from now on"/"Do not ask again" so there is no way round this one extra click every time.

Anyone could provide a hint as to where to go to make this happen without having this extra click every time please?

Additional Info: before the "Open" Option appears, there is something like "security check" (sorry we only have a german MSIE "Sicherheitsüberprüfung wird ausgeführt") in the bottom bar in the browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colleagues found out: It is (again) the "**Smart Screen Filter**" in MSIE that is causing the problem, disabling it in the Security Tab/Site Settings in the MSIE Internet options (for the level that the site delivering the jnlp) fixes the issue.

Comment: *"disabling it in the Security .. fixes the issue."* (sigh) Security measures are there for a reason. You should not recommend to clients to adjust their security in order to user your application, it is a vector for attacks. So in my view, you've not 'fixed the issue' so much as *exacerbated* the problem by not fixing it, and instead creating a security hole in the user's system.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, sure you are right. We are not sure however in what extent the issue is affected by the test systems not being connected to the internet and the setting can be adjusted in MSIE (in version 9) according to the "zone" the site is in (e.g. local intranet). It would be cutsomers' decision if they need to sacrifice that bit of security for the avoidance of the extra click. Smart Screen Filter is a MSIE feature AFAIK without analog on other browsers and on MSIE v7 e.g. causes the jws applet to be started twice on the test systems due to not being able to reach internet.