# Internet Explorer 11: Security settings to get the “open” option with JNLP files?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, jnlp

IE 11: When I click on a certain link (on a web page), which returns a JNLP file, I am asked if I want to *open*, *save* or *cancel*. However one customer also uses IE 11 and only gets the *save* and cancel options at the same link.

Exactly which settings are necessary to also get the *open* option?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854242/avoid-jnlp-open-click-in-msie9/37855417#37855417

Comment: Or maybe the one customer does not have java installed (or MSIE not aware of the java installation) so it simply does not know how to open it. What happens when it is saved, can he open it by double-clicking?

Comment: Java is installed. And the application can be started when saving the JNLP file first. On IE 11 on my machine, the SmartScreen Filter is activated and the Open button is still available.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the Smart Screen Filter on your machine so you get rid of the "Open..." question. - On the other machine, my feeling is that the application settings for MSIE do not tell it to use java to open jnlp or maybe the Content-type of the jnlp is not served correctly (`application/x-java-jnlp-file`)?

Comment: Enabling/disabling that filter does not seem to have any effect on the open/save/cancel dialog on my system (IE 11 on Windows 10). As for the content-type I'm not sure how to check this easily. However there is only one single customer who has this problem, and thousands of customers who don't. Thus I doubt the content-type is not set correctly.